# Refresh Domain Credentials Cache via command-line

Tags: command-line, batch, domain, windows-domain

Is there a way to refresh the cache a domain-computer keeps to store domain passwords?  I have a PC that is infrequently on the network, and the occasion happens where I would like the manually update the stores users' passwords when a domain-connection occurs.

Please note, this is for a command-line method, not a 'lock, unlock with new password' or any non-CLI method.  Uses will include, but will not be limited to, batch-file use.

Comment: You just want to refresh one specific credential?

Comment: @EBGreen Yes- but all would be better.

Comment: For a specific one, you can just use the runas command to run anything providing the proper credentials.